# Ordens da data de uma referência no meio de outras datas e referências

Tags: microsoft-excel, tabela-html

A situação fica mais simples de ser compreendida com um cenário hipotético.

Imagine que eu comprei 3 peças:

Peça A

Peça B

Peça C.

O fornecedor, como não tinha tudo a pronta entrega, dividiu a entrega das peças em 3 Notas Fiscais:

Nota Fiscal 1 - emitida em 10/08/2018

Nota Fiscal 2 - emitida em 12/08/2018

Nota Fiscal 3 - emitida em 14/08/2018

O resultado é então visto na tabela abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que quero fazer agora** (de forma automática, imagino que através de uma combinação de n fórmulas) **é classificar a ordem das Notas Fiscais de acordo com sua data de emissão para cada peça**. Por exemplo, o que quero é:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso porque a Nota Fiscal 1 foi a primeira a ser emitida, a Nota Fiscal 2 a segunda, e a Nota Fiscal 3 a terceira.

O problema é que a tabela não é organizada, havendo uma intercalação da ordem das peças e ordem das Notas Fiscais.

Alguma ideia?

Obrigado

Comment: Não da para filtrar a Referência desejada para a peça, por exemplo `Peça A` e depois classificar em datas do Mais Antigo para o Mais Novo? Manualmente nos filtros da tabela.

Comment: é que eu preciso tirar TODA intervenção manual na base de dados...sem filtrar, classificar etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilizando a fórmula: `=SOMARPRODUTO(($A2=$A$2:$A$7)*($C2>$C$2:$C$7))+1` é possível ordenar as datas por grupos da coluna A.

[image: Resultado]

Em que a fórmula é inserida na célula D2 e depois replicada para as demais células [com o Autopreenchimento](https://support.office.com/pt-br/article/preencher-dados-automaticamente-nas-c%C3%A9lulas-da-planilha-74e31bdd-d993-45da-aa82-35a236c5b5db).

```
+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+
| Referência | Nota Fiscal | Data de emissão da Nota Fiscal | ordem |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+
| Peça A     |        1001 | 10/08/2018                     |     2 |
| Peça A     |        1002 | 12/08/2018                     |     3 |
| Peça A     |        1003 | 09/08/2018                     |     1 |
| Peça B     |        1004 | 12/08/2018                     |     1 |
| Peça B     |        1005 | 14/08/2018                     |     2 |
| Peça C     |        1006 | 10/08/2018                     |     1 |
+------------+-------------+--------------------------------+-------+
```

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>Referência</th><th>Nota Fiscal</th><th>Data de emissão da Nota Fiscal</th><th>ordem</th></tr><tr><td>Peça A</td><td>1001</td><td>10/08/2018</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Peça A</td><td>1002</td><td>12/08/2018</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>Peça A</td><td>1003</td><td>09/08/2018</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Peça B</td><td>1004</td><td>12/08/2018</td><td>1</td></tr><tr><td>Peça B</td><td>1005</td><td>14/08/2018</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>Peça C</td><td>1006</td><td>10/08/2018</td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Show!! Obrigado